# Expected size of intersection in a scale-free directed graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Let $W$ be the Wikipedia graph, in which every page $p_i$ is represented by a vertex $v_i$, and there is a directed edge between two vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ if page $p_i$ links page $p_j$.

This graph is known to be scale-free, that is, the degree distribution follows a power law.

Let $v_i$ and $v_j$ be vertices representing pages $p_i$ and $p_j$. Let $N(v_i)$ and $N(v_j)$ be the set of vertices representing pages linked respectively from $p_i$ and $p_j$. What is $\mathrm{E}[|N(v_i)\cap N(v_j)|]$, the expected size of their intersection? What is its distribution?

**EDIT:** I think I can restate this question as follows. This is not a perfect translation, but hopefully should be good enough for my purposes.

I have $|W|$ bins, $n_1$ red balls and $n_2$ blue balls. When I throw a ball, it will land in bin $i$ with known probability $p_i$. When I'm done throwing all balls, what's the expected number of bins with balls of two colors in it?

**EDIT2:** This simpler problem has a simpler solution. Define $n_{1}n_{2}$
random variables $I_{ij}$ indicating that red ball $i$ and blue ball $j$ landed in the same bin. If we assume independence, then $$\mathrm{E}[|N_1\cap N_2|] = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n_1,n_j}{\mathrm{E}[I_{ij}]} = n_{1}n_{2}\sum_{i=1}^{|W|}{p_{i}^2}\text{.}$$

[**Motivation:** I'm trying to build a similarity measure on pairs of pages from Wikipedia using the local connectivity data. Since I can compute the actual intersection size, I want to use the probability of deviation from the expected size as a similarity measure between the two pages.]

Comment: Why not directly use the actual intersection size as your similarity measure? (Or you can find the intersection size for a large number of pairs of pages, and take the average.)

Comment: I tried both approaches, and they perform poorly against the common benchmarking datasets.

Comment: The algorithm resulting from the independence assumption performs acceptably. A few more details can be found in this presentation: https://github.com/jacquerie/IR/blob/master/slide.pdf?raw=true